# Where Do Image Dimensions Get Added To A Filename?

Tags: php, images

I'm trying to replace the naming convention of uploaded images. I need to reference images in my css dynamically do the medium size rather than the base image. The problem is that the resized images have no consistency in their names, keeping aspect ratio means that the width will be the same (as set) but height will vary. Appending the size name instead of the dimensions is the goal, where do image dimensions get added to a filename?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can I ask why? Just because if you think you need it because you're trying to 'guess' the filename in some code, then that would be the wrong approach.

Comment: @JacobPeattie there's gallery code that is loading the full image version as a background url (inline style). So I need a consistent naming convention for the reduced sizes so I can reference them instead of the full sized versions.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know the filenames to do that. If your _real_ question is how to get the filename of the full size or other size version of an image, then ask that, including code. Changing the filenames is not the solution you're looking for.